# Python Web Scraping - Issue

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need a help to fill out the following web scraping code.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.spc.lk/products.php"

data  = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
tesla_revenue = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Item Code", "Description", "Unit", "Supplier", "W/S Rs.Price", "Retail Rs.Price", "Disc"])
for row in soup.find_all('tbody')[1].find_all('tr'):
    col = row.find_all("td")
    Item_Code = col[0].text
    Description = col[1].text
    Unit = col[2].text
    Supplier = col[3].text
    W_SRs.Price = col[4].text
    RetailRs.Price = col[5].text
    Disc = col[6].text
    tablet_prices = tablet_prices.append({"Item Code":Item_Code,"Description":Description,"Unit":Unit,"Supplier":Supplier,"W/S Rs.Price":W_SRs.Price,"Retail Rs.Price":RetailRs.Price,"Disc":Disc}, ignore_index=True) 
    
print(tablet_prices)
```

This gives me the below result.

for row in soup.find_all('tbody')[1].find_all('tr'):

IndexError: list index out of range

can you help me to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried looking at your actual data? Why don't you print out your `data` variable or your soup variable formatted using `print(soup.prettify())`. This is one of the biggest keys to learning how to web scrape... LOOK AT THE RESPONSE! Tell me what you see when you try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the website you attempting to access does not recognize your Python-code as a valid browser/User-Agent and therefore returns a status-code 406, rather than the expected status-code 200 (If you look at your data.text you will also see that it responds with: "Not Acceptable! - An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security."). Therefore you need to add a valid browser-description to your request header in order for it to return a valid response (I found mine using the program Fiddler.):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.spc.lk/products.php"
header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'}
data = requests.get(url, headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html5lib')
tablet_prices = []
for row in soup.find_all('tbody')[1].find_all('tr')[1:]:
    col = row.find_all("td")
    tablet_dict = {"Item Code": col[0].text, "Description": col[1].text, "Unit": col[2].text, "Supplier": col[3].text,
         "W/S Rs.Price": col[4].text, "Retail Rs.Price": col[5].text, "Disc": col[6].text}
    tablet_prices.append(tablet_dict)
print(tablet_prices)
```

I adjusted the code to get the data in a simple manner that stores each tr as an individual dictionary inside a list, which should make it relatively simple to access and convert into any other format.

Comment: thanks. but when running the above, im getting an error message NameError: name 'W_SRs' is not defined. Can you tell me the reason? I really new to python.

Comment: The reason for that is that you are trying to assign it to the Price attribute of the object W_SRs. (I assumed it was intended, so I did not adjust it.) I will make an adjustment to the suggested solution.